# Is there a standard formula to calculate the optimal resource required by SQL Server base on the Ram size of the server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My server that SQL Server runs on has 8GB of Ram. Is there a standard formula that DBA use to gauge the minimum and maximum resource to be allocated for SQL Server base on the server Ram size?

I need to know how much of MB is optimal for these settings:

- Minimum Server Memory(MB)
- Maximum Server Memory(MB) and
- Minimum memory per query.

My research get me to this link:[Guideline](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/suggested-max-memory-settings-for-sql-server-20052008/)

But I think the best solution is to know how he get to those figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that you pointed out gives a good starting number, which in most cases is sufficient enough as a good configuration.

I would suggest you to leave min memory as DEFAULT and adjust the max memory.

Also, best is to baseline your database server usage during your full business cycle as that will give you the best number based on your workload using below PERFMON counters :

- SQL Server:Buffer Manager\Page Life Expectancy
- SQL Server:Buffer Manager\Page reads/sec
- Physical Disk\Disk Reads/sec
- Memory\Available Mbytes
- SQL Server: Memory Manager - Total Server Memory
- SQL Server: Memory Manager - Target Server Memory

**Note:** If you are going to use any formula or online calculator to calculate SQL Server memory configuration then best is to read [Beaware of Wow… An online calculator to misconfigure your SQL Server memory ! - by Jonathan Kehayias](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/wow-an-online-calculator-to-misconfigure-your-sql-server-memory/)  first.

Some good references :

[How much memory does my SQL Server actually need?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/) - by Jonathan Kehayias