# App domain crashed due to not enough storage available to process this command

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, ssms

We are running SQL server **SQL 2014 12.0.2000.8** 32 bit running on **Windows 2008 server** 32 bit.

This server is also part of T-Replication as a publisher and also distributor.

The server has 16 GB of RAM and has allocated Max Memory 2147483647 MB (Default setting) to SQL server.

Since yesterday I am getting the below error whenever start the SSMS. To solve it, I restarted SQL Server Service, then I am able to login to SQL Server, but after a few hours it happens again.

[image]

Please provide me help with any idea where to look to trouble shoot the issue.

Comment: Start with this Q&A ["When should I not set the maximum memory in SQL Server"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69639/when-should-i-not-set-the-maximum-server-memory-option-in-sql-server)

Comment: SQL Server 2014 is not supported on Windows server 2008. Plus your SQL Server 2014 is not even patched to latest service pack. Moreover you can solve this issue by using 64 bit of both SQL Server and Windows OS

Comment: I add service pack 2(now my Sql Server is 12.0.5000.0).But i can't use 64 bit OS because PIKA(telephonic card) card is not supported 64 bit OS this is our limitation.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually down to memory pressure, I assume that you're running SSMS on the SQL server?  Try opening SSMS from another location and connect in, does this still produce the error?

You might want to set your max memory setting to allow some breathing space for the OS and other apps.  I usually leave the OS 4GB to start with and then tune from there if I need to.

Comment: I add service pack 2(now my Sql Server is 12.0.5000.0).But i can't use 64 bit OS because PIKA(telephonic card) card is not supported 64 bit OS this is our limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows Server 2008 is Standard 32bit then the max memory is 4GB.  If it is enterprise or data center then the max memory for 32 bit 64GB.

I do agree with David that you have memory pressure.

Here is a link to server memory limits
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Actually the max memory which SQL Server can utilize under default condition would be 2 GB. The total VAS is 4 GB equally divided between SQL Server and OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your CLR code is doing, but I think your problem is described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/106167/error-message-not-enough-server-storage-is-available-to-process-this-c

Solution is also included in the link.